# Comparing two dataframes if a column from both has a common entry

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two csv files and I am using R-

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CSLDs9qQXPMqMegdsWK2cQI_64B9org7

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mVp1s0m4OZNNctVBn5JXIYK1JPsp-aiw

As is visible from the files, each file has a list of dates running from 2008 to the present along with other columns.

I want my output to be two files, but both should contain rows of data for the dates present in both files.

For eg. say date X is not there on 1 file, then it should be removed from the other file where it is present as well. Only dates and the corresponding rows present on both columns should survive on both output files.

I tried the inner_join function in the dplyr library but that didn't work because the dates are in factor format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the factor conversion of character strings by adding `stringAsFactors = F`. In addition, in your dataset you have NA coded as the string `null`, so you should also specify this in the call to `read.csv`

```
path1 <- "the path for the first dataset KS"
path2 <- "the path for the second dataset 105560.KS"
df1 <- read.csv(path1,stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- read.csv(path2,stringsAsFactors = F,na.strings = "null")

df_comb <- inner_join(df1,df2,by = "Date")
```